# Google Marker Click Event Not Working But Map Click Event Is

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a clickable marker on a map with the google maps javascript api.  When I click the marker nothing happens.  However when i set the click event to the map instead of the marker i can click anywhere and the console will log "Click" and an info window will popup at the marker.  Both marker and map are declared at the same point in scope so why one works and not the other i can't figure out.
Here is my code right now:

```
window.onload = function() {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var pos;
        // The location of Uluru
        var uluru = { lat: 43.221009, lng: -79.865291 };
        // The map, centered at Uluru
        var map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), { zoom: 12, center: uluru });
        // The marker, positioned at Uluru

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                pos = {
                    lat: position.coords.latitude,
                    lng: position.coords.longitude
                };
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: pos, map: map });                
                map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function () {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: uluru, map: map });
            });
        }
        else {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: uluru, map: map });             
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        } 

        marker.addListener('click', function (){
            showInfoWindow();
        });
        function showInfoWindow() {
            console.log("Click");
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Your Location');
            infoWindow.open(map);
        }

        function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        }     

    };
```

Ive also tried doing the listener like this:

```
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function (){
            showInfoWindow();
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geolocation service is asynchronous.  You are "adding" the listener to the marker before it has been created.  Add the listener to the marker when you create it (or use a "createMarker" function that creates the marker and adds the click listener to it).

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/d98ubw6x/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var pos;
  // The location of Uluru
  var uluru = {
    lat: 43.221009,
    lng: -79.865291
  };
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: uluru
    });
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pos,
        map: map
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        showInfoWindow();
      });
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: uluru,
        map: map
      });
    });
  } else {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      showInfoWindow();
    });
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }

  function showInfoWindow() {
    console.log("Click");
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent('Your Location');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
      'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
      'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
    infoWindow.open(map);
  }
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try passing the event parameter to your function.

```
 `marker.addListener('click', function (event){` 
   if (event) {
      showInfoWindow();
   }     
  });
```

Comment: I tried this:
 marker.addListener('click', function (event) { 
            console.log("Click");
            if (event) {
                showInfoWindow();
            }     
        });

Comment: it did not even log the "Click"

Comment: try console log on marker and check what type of object is, then follow the logic until you have a marker type object

Comment: console.log before the event listener but after marker is set shows that it exists: _.nf {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, animation: 2, gm_bindings_: {…}, clickable: true, …}